# Why do I get 'Connecting to invalid output of source node' error with a Tensorflow-Hub KerasLayer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

**Edit:** I tried turning on eager execution to see if I could identify exactly where the issue was occuring, and eager execution stopped the errors and made it run successfully. No idea why that would be the case and unfortunately that really doesn't help me.

**Original Post:** I'm pretty new to Tensorflow and I'm trying to understand how to use Tensorflow-Hub modules in a tf.keras model. My goal is to create an email classification system to route emails in my organization.

I have already built a model using data that was pre-processed using the universal sentence encoder module. This was an RNN and worked quite effectively, but I'm interested in whether I can improve my accuracy.

Now I want to incorporate the module directly into my neural net so I can train it.

I'm running this in a Jupyter Notebook.

I built a simple, non-RNN model to try and get the Tensorflow-Hub module training.

```py
print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")

hub_module = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128/1"
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(hub.KerasLayer(hub_module, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.build()
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', 'mae'])

#Fake data
train_data = [["Hello how are you"], ["Goodbye my friend"], ["Happiness is a warm slice of toast"]]
train_labels = [[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1]]

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

Here is my full console output:

```
Version:  1.14.0
Eager mode:  False
Hub version:  0.6.0
GPU is available
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer_5 (KerasLayer)   (None, 128)               124642688 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 195       
=================================================================
Total params: 124,667,651
Trainable params: 124,667,651
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected a shuffled dataset but input dataset `x` is not shuffled. Please invoke `shuffle()` on input dataset.

WARNING:tensorflow:Expected a shuffled dataset but input dataset `x` is not shuffled. Please invoke `shuffle()` on input dataset.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1355     try:
-> 1356       return fn(*args)
   1357     except errors.OpError as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1338       # Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the runtime.
-> 1339       self._extend_graph()
   1340       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _extend_graph(self)
   1373     with self._graph._session_run_lock():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1374       tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)
   1375 

InvalidArgumentError: Node 'Adam/gradients/keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall': Connecting to invalid output 1 of source node keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-492e87ad5d5d> in <module>
     28 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
     29 
---> 30 model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1, verbose=2)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    778           validation_steps=validation_steps,
    779           validation_freq=validation_freq,
--> 780           steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    781 
    782   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    139       reset_dataset_after_each_epoch = True
    140       steps_per_epoch = training_utils.infer_steps_for_dataset(
--> 141           inputs, steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs, steps_name=steps_name)
    142     input_iterator = _get_iterator(inputs, model._distribution_strategy)
    143 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in infer_steps_for_dataset(dataset, steps, epochs, steps_name)
   1391   """
   1392   assert isinstance(dataset, dataset_ops.DatasetV2)
-> 1393   size = K.get_value(cardinality.cardinality(dataset))
   1394   if size == cardinality.INFINITE and steps is None:
   1395     raise ValueError('When passing an infinitely repeating dataset, you '

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in get_value(x)
   2987     return function([], x)(x)
   2988 
-> 2989   return x.eval(session=get_session((x,)))
   2990 
   2991 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in get_session(op_input_list)
    460   if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
    461     with session.graph.as_default():
--> 462       _initialize_variables(session)
    463   return session
    464 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in _initialize_variables(session)
    877     # marked as initialized.
    878     is_initialized = session.run(
--> 879         [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])
    880     uninitialized_vars = []
    881     for flag, v in zip(is_initialized, candidate_vars):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    948     try:
    949       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 950                          run_metadata_ptr)
    951       if run_metadata:
    952         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1171     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1172       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1173                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1174     else:
   1175       results = []

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1348     if handle is None:
   1349       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1350                            run_metadata)
   1351     else:
   1352       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1368           pass
   1369       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1370       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1371 
   1372   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Node 'Adam/gradients/keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall': Connecting to invalid output 1 of source node keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs
```

Comment: Not sure you should be calling `model.build`.

Comment: Removing model.build doesn't change my results unfortunately.

Comment: Then the next attempt is to add the actual `input_shape=some_tuple`.

Comment: Yes, when setting the input shape (which should just be 1 as far as I can tell - since the sentence input is a single string) the error is:         ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature: inputs ((<tf.Tensor 'keras_layer_7_input:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=string>,)), input_signature ((TensorSpec(shape=(?,), dtype=tf.string, name=''),))

Comment: Upgrading to the 2.0 RC seems to have resolved this issue for me. It's not quite working yet but I believe that I should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: You might benefit from using a functional API model instead of a sequential. Not sure the keras hub layer is expecting an input shape like that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by upgrading to the TF 2.0 RC from TF 1.14.